# gRPC HealthCheck reports SERVING even when it is defined as NOT_SERVING

Tags: python, server, grpc, health-check

I am trying to create a server with two services and a HealthCheck in each one, so I can check them independently and use reflection to know the methods exposed in each one. I have hardcoded one service as NOT_SERVING to test it, however, for some reason, it is not working. I would appreciate some help.

I have created a short script to reproduce this result.

The proto file definition:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package test;

service Greeter {
    rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

message HelloRequest {
    string name = 1;
}

message HelloReply {
    string message = 1;
}

service Byeer {
    rpc SayBye (ByeRequest) returns (ByeReply) {}
}

message ByeRequest {
    string name = 1;
}

message ByeReply {
    string message = 1;
}
```

The Python server:

```py
from concurrent import futures
import grpc
from grpc_health.v1 import health, health_pb2, health_pb2_grpc
from grpc_reflection.v1alpha import reflection
import test_pb2_grpc
import test_pb2


class Greeter(test_pb2_grpc.GreeterServicer):

    def SayHello(self, request, context):
        return test_pb2.HelloReply(message='Hello, %s!' % request.name)

    def Check(self, request, context):
        return health_pb2.HealthCheckResponse(status=health_pb2.HealthCheckResponse.SERVING)

    def Watch(self, request, context):
        return health_pb2.HealthCheckResponse(status=health_pb2.HealthCheckResponse.UNIMPLEMENTED)


class Byeer(test_pb2_grpc.ByeerServicer):

    def SayBye(self, request, context):
        return test_pb2.HelloReply(message='Bye, %s!' % request.name)

    def Check(self, request, context):
        return health_pb2.HealthCheckResponse(status=health_pb2.HealthCheckResponse.NOT_SERVING)

    def Watch(self, request, context):
        return health_pb2.HealthCheckResponse(status=health_pb2.HealthCheckResponse.UNIMPLEMENTED)


def run_server():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=None))
    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:8000')

    test_pb2_grpc.add_GreeterServicer_to_server(Greeter(), server)
    health_pb2_grpc.add_HealthServicer_to_server(Greeter(), server)

    test_pb2_grpc.add_ByeerServicer_to_server(Byeer(), server)
    health_pb2_grpc.add_HealthServicer_to_server(Byeer(), server)

    services = tuple(service.full_name for service in health_pb2.DESCRIPTOR.services_by_name.values())
    services += tuple(service.full_name for service in test_pb2.DESCRIPTOR.services_by_name.values())
    services += (reflection.SERVICE_NAME,)
    reflection.enable_server_reflection(services, server)

    server.start()
    server.wait_for_termination()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_server()
```

When I test the reflection and the server methods, it works:

```sh
grpcurl -plaintext localhost:8000 list
grpcurl -plaintext localhost:8000 list test.Byeer
grpcurl -plaintext localhost:8000 list test.Greeter
grpcurl --plaintext -d '{"name": "John Doe"}' localhost:8000 test.Greeter/SayHello
grpcurl --plaintext -d '{"name": "John Doe"}' localhost:8000 test.Byeer/SayBye
```

The reflections report the proper methods and the server the correct response.

The HealthCheck on the server and the Greeter service work too:

```sh
grpcurl --plaintext -d '' localhost:8000 grpc.health.v1.Health/Check
grpcurl --plaintext -d '{"service": "test.Greeter"}' localhost:8000 grpc.health.v1.Health/Check
```

So, it reports SERVING as expected.

However, the HealthCheck on the Byeer service, and whatever other name I use, also reports SERVING:

```sh
grpcurl --plaintext -d '{"service": "test.Byeer"}' localhost:8000 grpc.health.v1.Health/Check
grpcurl --plaintext -d '{"service": "xxx"}' localhost:8000 grpc.health.v1.Health/Check
```

And I would expect NOT_SERVING since the Check methods for the Byeer has been hardcoded as NOT_SERVING.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

OK, here's a working example that excludes the reflection (my laziness):

```py
from concurrent import futures
import grpc

from grpc_health.v1.health import HealthServicer
from grpc_health.v1 import health_pb2, health_pb2_grpc

import test_pb2_grpc
import test_pb2


class Greeter(test_pb2_grpc.GreeterServicer):

    def __init__(self,health):
        super().__init__()
        self.health=health

    def SayHello(self, request, context):
        self.health.set(
            "greeter-eater",
            health_pb2.HealthCheckResponse.ServingStatus.Value("SERVING"),
        )
        return test_pb2.HelloReply(message='Hello, %s!' % request.name)

class Byeer(test_pb2_grpc.ByeerServicer):

    def __init__(self,health):
        super().__init__()
        self.health=health

    def SayBye(self, request, context):
        self.health.set(
            "byeer-flyer",
            health_pb2.HealthCheckResponse.ServingStatus.Value("NOT_SERVING"),
        )
        return test_pb2.HelloReply(message='Bye, %s!' % request.name)

def main():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))

    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')

    # As with any other Servicer implementations, register it
    health = HealthServicer()

    # Provide other services with a way to update health
    greeter = Greeter(health)
    byeer = Byeer(health)

    test_pb2_grpc.add_GreeterServicer_to_server(
        greeter,
        server,
    )
    test_pb2_grpc.add_ByeerServicer_to_server(
        byeer,
        server,
    )
    health_pb2_grpc.add_HealthServicer_to_server(
        health,
        server,
    )

    server.start()
    server.wait_for_termination()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Without reflection, I needed to grab a copy of [`health.proto`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grpc/grpc/master/src/proto/grpc/health/v1/health.proto) and:

```sh
# Invoke Greeter/SayHello
grpcurl \
--plaintext \
-d '{"name": "Freddie"}' \
-import-path ${PWD}/protos \
-proto health.proto \
-proto test.proto \
localhost:50051 test.Greeter/SayHello
{
  "message": "Hello, Freddie!"
}

# Invoke Byeer/SayBye
grpcurl \
--plaintext \
-d '{"name": "Freddie"}' \
-import-path ${PWD}/protos \
-proto health.proto \
-proto test.proto \
localhost:50051 test.Byeer/SayBye
{
  "message": "Bye, Freddie!"
}

# Health/Check Greeter service aka "greeter-eater"
grpcurl \
--plaintext \
-d '{"service":"greeter-eater"}' \
-import-path ${PWD}/protos \
-proto health.proto \
-proto test.proto \
localhost:50051 grpc.health.v1.Health/Check
{
  "status": "SERVING"
}

# Health/Check Byeer service aka "byeer-flyer"
grpcurl \
--plaintext \
-d '{"service":"byeer-flyer"}' \
-import-path ${PWD}/protos \
-proto health.proto \
-proto test.proto \
localhost:50051 grpc.health.v1.Health/Check
{
  "status": "NOT_SERVING"
}
```

Explanation:

1. You need only register `HealthServicer` once per server.
2. As with any gRPC server, it (`HealthServicer`), when you invoke its methods (e.g. `Check`), you need to provide it with some context. In this case, which service.
3. The `service` names aren't bound to the proto packages but to an arbitrary string that you define when you `set(SERVICE,health_pb2.HealthCheckResponse.ServingStatus`)
4. Because you can register multiple distinct gRPC services (`Greeter`,`Byeer`) with a single server, these need to be able to provide health context back to `HealthServicer`
5. In order for other gRPC services to update the healthcheck service, we need to share some of the healthcheck service's context with the other services; here I'm using the Servicer itself.
6. Other services may update their status by using `set` and providing some (preferably) unique identifier; there's no need for this to match the server's proto package/Service (but that may be a good strategy).
7. In practice you would not `set` with static `ServingStatus.Value`'s but would accurately reflect that service's status

Comment: Thanks for the help, for the good explanation of why there is a problem in my approach, and to explain how to solve it. Now it works.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm pleased to hear it